# javascript object creating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object like this

```
 var student = function () {
     this.id = 1;
     this.Name = "Shohel";
     this.Roll = "04115407";
     this.Session = "03-04";
     this.Subject = "CSE";
 };
```

and i have a javascript array list like this

```
var students = [];
```

now i want to push student into students, this is shown below

```
students.push(new student())  //no prolem

students.push(new student[id = 3]) //Problem
```

here second line occurs exceptions, how can i push javascript object like as c# add list, which is representing second line? thanks

Comment: So what are you expecting when you try to call a function with brackets and not parenthesis ?

Comment: I want to set default value of student when i push into students

Comment: You have not provided for any way to pass values into your object class.

Comment: but i can do the same work in c# , without providing parameter, is it possible in javascript?

Comment: JavaScript is not C#. They are different languages and work differently. If you can something like this in C# then the answer is no, you can't do that in JavaScript. I really recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial if you intend to use this language: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply can't, what you can do though is accept a config as a parameter to your constructor and read it like this

```
var student = function (config) {
                config = config || {};
                this.id = config.id || 1;
                this.Name = config.Name || "Shohel";
                this.Roll = config.Roll || "04115407";
                this.Session = config.Session || "03-04";
                this.Subject = config.Subject || "CSE";
            };
```

And call it like this

```
students.push(new student({id: 3}));
```

---

**EDIT, PREFERRED ONE**

Just as [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) pointed out if you want to get rid of the repititive `||` for default values, you can use jQuery to pass them

```
var student = function (config) {
                    var defaults = {
                        id: 1,
                        Name: "Shohel",
                        Roll: "04115407",
                        Session: "03-04",
                        Subject: "CSE"
                    };
                    config = $.extend(defaults, config || {});
                    this.id = config.id;
                    this.Name = config.Name;
                    this.Roll = config.Roll;
                    this.Session = config.Session;
                    this.Subject = config.Subject;
                };
```

Comment: this answer I was waiting... ;) +1

Comment: as a sidenote, you can remove most of those ugly OR's by just defining the object in `config = config || {id:1, Name:'Shohel' ...}`

Comment: @adeneo not really... unless you're sure each property will be specified. The OP's sample only has the `id` property set.

Comment: I thought of that but if config is actually defined and all of the parameters are not defined you can get ugly values, i.e. undefined.

Comment: If that's an issue, the question is tagged jQuery, so just do `config = $.extend(config, defaults)` etc. and you can remove all the ugly OR's

Comment: maybe you could use `.extend()` of jQuery, the OP did tag jQuery ;) well, just a suggestion..

Comment: You beat me on this one thanks for the advice I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: Just one thing... wouldn't it rather be `config = $.extend(defaults, config)` ?

Comment: Okay can you be a bit more precise ? What error or behaviour do you get ?

Comment: I think I got it, I missed a closing brace with the push part.

Answer (score 6):

Make the values that are variable **parameters** of the function. For example:

```
var Student = function (id) {
  this.id = id;
  // ...
};

students.push(new Student(3));
```

---

I recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial about functions:

- [MDN - JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [Eloquent JavaScript - Functions](http://quirksmode.org/js/function.html)
- [quirksmode.org - Functions](http://quirksmode.org/js/function.html)